# Pivot table with specific logic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

Please help,

I'm trying to pivot sql server table like this:

[image]

To get something like this:

[image]

I've tried to do that in excel but it didn't work for me as it's duplicating attributes etc.
So, is there a query to pivot table to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server's `pivot` only works if you pivot on one column.  Since you're pivoting on `(Item Id, Lot Number)`, you have to do it the old fashioned way:

```
select  [Item Id]
,       [Lot Number]
,       sum(case when Attribute = 'PPA' then Value end) as PPA
,       sum(case when Attribute = 'PU0' then Value end) as PU0
,       ...
from    YourTable
group by
        [Item Id]
,       [Lot Number]
```

Answer (score 2):

See @Andomar's answer for writing a SQL query to do the pivot. But if you just want to use Excel it should work fine putting ItemId and Lot Number in rows, put Attribute in column section and Value in data section. You'll need to remove all the subtotal rows that Excel likes to add, which you do from the Properties of each field (if I remember correctly).

If that doesn't work, can you post an image of what happens in Excel that you don't like?

Answer (score 0):

use sql like this?
case when LotNumber=5 and arribut = 'PPA' 
       then value
end

and other colum also like these script,have a try